# How to get position of object in plane

Tags: opengl

At my game screen console one triangle and one circle is moving randomly. I want to get present position of triangle and circle.How will i do it ? I have to check distance between them.

Comment: How will i know the triangle and circle position if i ant to calculate distance.

Comment: 'I' is capitalized, space after a period, no space before a question-mark, greetings are unnecessary.

Comment: This is OpenGL-related...how?

Comment: My triangle ad circle is rendering by opengl.

Comment: is  glTranslatef(); function gives position of object ?

Comment: There is not enough information in your question for anyone to have any clue how to solve your problem. You need to be much more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This highly depends on how you move the triangle and the circle. I suppose you at least have the circle's local center already, since that's needed to define a circle. For the triangle's local center, try google or any decent math book.

I assume you issue a bunch of `glTranslate` calls with random parameters. You could get the current modelview matrix and extract the translation component, but I'd advice against that. It should be easier for you to track the parameters manually, since if you only have `glTranslate` it would be a simple addition. In conjunction with `glRotate` this would be somewhat more complicated, but since those functions are deprecated already, you'd need to do the tracking yourself anyway (roll your own matrix math or preferably use a library).